# Stop chrome extensions from injecting code into multipart response

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Some extensions seem to want to modify the response of a request:
It changes the response from regular JSON:

```
{"fields":"A, B, C","success":true}
```

to this:

```
{"fields":"A, B, C","success":true}<script type="text/javascript">(function () {
            return window.SIG_EXT = {};
          })()</script>"
```

This specific one is by the HubSpot Sidekick extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidekick-by-hubspot/oiiaigjnkhngdbnoookogelabohpglmd

Is there any way to prevent this, aside from uninstalling the extension?

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the engineers working on the Sidekick extension. I wanted to give you a heads up that I've looked into this problem and diagnosed it as a small error in our JS code that was causing certain sites which fetched JSON to end up with adulterated payloads. This error has been fixed in the latest version of Sidekick (v2.4.49) released this afternoon and should not appear again. My apologies for any inconvenience the problem may have caused in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks very much for fixing that!
I'd still be interested in finding a general way to prevent this, not all extension developers are good web citizens :)

Comment: I've had this issue (window.SIG_EXT too), and disabling the Hubspot Sales extension stopped the injection from happening. Current version: 2.6.67.

Comment: @Giuseppe

I'm using the HubSpot Sales extension v.2.6.70 and I can confirm that this is still an issue, unless the extension is disabled.

Comment: Still happening in 2.6.92 :(